# Another way to solve an indefinite integral for students of an high school

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof

I have this indefinite integral , with $a\in \Bbb R, \: a\neq 0$

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}, \tag 1$$

I solve the integral $(1)$ with $x=at$, and using this approach,

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}=\cdots =\int \frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}dx=\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+x^2}+x \rvert+k, \quad k\in\Bbb R \tag 2$$

Is there a fast mode to solve the $(1)$ and the $(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $x= a\tan\theta$ for $(1)$ and $x=\tan \theta$ for $(2)$.

Comment: Yes and after I will have the $\sec$ :-). It is for my students of my high school. However thank you and I always vote up. Is there a reason for $x=\tan \theta$? My students remember not much.

Comment: @Sebastiano You could tell them to always consider a trig substitution whenever there is an $x^2$ term inside a square root, and then use trig identities to get rid of it.

Comment: You can't even imagine the effort I put in every day. Unfortunately, as the whole world is invaded by coronavirus and we do distance learning with the computer. :-( It's a struggle to explain four formulas that you can't imagine.

Comment: @Sebastiano Those inclined towards math will devise their own way to learn, and for the rest: let them be ;)

Comment: With all my heart I write to you: they're worse than children. They are never happy, you explain them the details but as soon as you make a mistake, not resolution, they eat you more than a pit bull.

Comment: It’s pretty obvious that highlighting others’  mistakes is a sign of insecurity about being bad at a particular field yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your high school students have learned about the hyperbolic functions, then there is a natural substitution based on the identity $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$.

Therefore, if we make the substitution $x=a\sinh(t)$ such that  $dx=a\cosh(t)\,dt$, then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\,dx&=\int \frac{1}{a\cosh(t)}\,a\cosh(t)\,dt\\\\
&=t+C\\\\
&=\text{arsinh}(x/a)+C\\\\
&=\frac1a \log\left( x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)+C'
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very kind I smile for not to cry. But if they fatigue even for a basic change in logarithms. They haven't done the hyperbolic functions which in my humble opinion should be done by correlating everything to the hyperbole conic. I'm sick and tired and discouraged and tired of hearing students whine. They want everything and now. Thank you very much and I give my thank you in another way.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, indeed.  Even today's college students typically view themselves as "buyers," and believe that their having paid for a class entitles them to a passing grade (regardless of performance).  Do you teach at a high school in the US?

Comment: You are welcome too and I saw a reply from you with the brown colored box using MathJaX :-). I teach in Sicily (Italy) in a scientific high school. I assure you it's a tragedy and I do research at the university (students feel like superheroes when they don't even know the basics of the subject). Many of my questions here are asked just to find a simple alternative for them. I invite you to take a look if and when you can.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute $ x  =  ai\sin(\theta)$ where $i^2 = -1$

Comment: Please Edit your post and use mathjax, and add details please.